# Create a calculated field in R at each record/row level

Tags: r, conditional-statements, dplyr

I have the below dataframe from which I intend to create a calculated field at each Code level or row level.

```
Code    count_pol       const_q
A028        12              3   
B09         7               4
M017        5               2
S83         4               1
S1960       6               4
S179        2               2
S193        3               3
```

IN the above dataset, I want to create a calculated field y for which the following conditions apply:

```
If for a code the count_pol lies in 1,2,3 , y = count_pol/const_q else const_q/4

Thus the expected output is:

Code    count_pol       const_q     y
A028        12              3       0.75
B09         7               4       1   
M017        5               2       0.5
S83         4               1       0.25
S1960       6               4       1
S179        2               2       1
S193        3               3       1
```

I have tried the below code:

```
a_df <- mutate(a_df,
                    y = if_else(count_pol %in% c(1:3), as.integer(const_q)/count_pol,const_q/4))
```

but that does not give the desired output.

Can someone please help me rectify this?

Answer (score 0):

We can use `if_else` to check for values in `1:3`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%  mutate(y = if_else(count_pol %in% 1:3, count_pol/const_q, const_q/4))

#   Code count_pol const_q    y
#1  A028        12       3 0.75
#2   B09         7       4 1.00
#3  M017         5       2 0.50
#4   S83         4       1 0.25
#5 S1960         6       4 1.00
#6  S179         2       2 1.00
#7  S193         3       3 1.00
```

and in base R that would be

```
transform(df, y = ifelse(count_pol %in% 1:3, count_pol/const_q, const_q/4))
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(Code = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 7L, 6L, 4L, 5L), 
.Label = c("A028", "B09", "M017", "S179", "S193", "S1960", "S83"), 
 class = "factor"), count_pol = c(12L, 7L, 5L, 4L, 6L, 2L, 3L), const_q = c(3L, 
4L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 3L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -7L))
```

Answer (score 0):

With case_when() ...

```
df %>%
group_by(code) %>%
mutate(
    y = case_when(
        count_pol %in% c(1, 2, 3) ~ count_pol/const_q,
        TRUE ~ const_q/4
        )
    )
```